# smplayer tearing

Tags: xubuntu, tearing, smplayer

I have a latitude e6410 with xubuntu installed. i have mpv installed, and i like to play my movies with smplayer. But i have tearing problem no matter what multimedia engine and video output i choose. everything is good on mpv and no tearing, but on smplayer when playing an action movie, the tearing problem is there.

```
$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: Intel Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       bus-ID: 00:02.0
       Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 )
       drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
       Resolution: 1440x900@60.00hz
       OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ironlake Mobile
       version: 2.1 Mesa 19.0.2 Direct Render: Yes
```

can you please tell me what is wrong? my device is old i gave up using ubuntu or mint and decidet to use a lightweight distro, so i installed xubuntu and still have this tearing problem, really need your help.

edit: While i was searching, someone said smplayer can not enable vsynce when slave a multimedia engine for example in my case MPV. I dont know if it's a bug or what, but i really need to make it work.

Comment: Just curious: Does this problem occur while smplayer is in full screen or in a window (smaller than full screen) or both?

Comment: intersting!! this occur just in full screen

Comment: Yes. Interesting. I had a similar case in Windows 7 with another player (I think it was VLC). But, I have no clue about its reason and/or solution.

Comment: well i am no programmer. I wish I was, so I could find the problem myself. nobody here helps. They say it's a bug in intel HD graphics, but why mpv is ok when it run on its own? I know there is something wrong with mpv running as slave in smplayer. 
but i don't remember these kind of problems on any version of windows. I work with windows everyday and installed it on a lots of computers, but never seen something like this, my machine does not tearing problem in windows.
 thanks for the reply :)